# Releasing memory usage by variable in python

Tags: python, macos, list, numpy, memory

I am currently trying to store some data into .h5 files, I quickly realised that might have to store my data into parts, as it is  not possible to process it an have in my ram. I started out using `numpy.array` to compress the memory usage, but that resulted in days spend on formatting data.

So i went back to use `list`, but made the program monitor the memory usage, 
when it was above a specified value, will a part be stored, as a `numpy` format - such that a another process can load it and make use of it.  Problem with doing this, is that what I thought would release my memory isn't releasing the memory.  For some reason is the memory the same even though I reset the variable and `del` the variable.  Why isn't the memory  being released here?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import resource
import sys
import gc
import math
import h5py
import SecureString
import objgraph
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided as ast

total_frames = 15
total_frames_with_deltas = total_frames*3
dim = 40
window_height = 5


def store_file(file_name,data):
    with h5py.File(file_name,'w') as f:
        f["train_input"] = np.concatenate(data,axis=1)

def load_data_overlap(saved):
    #os.chdir(numpy_train)
    print "Inside function!..."
    if saved == False:
        train_files = np.random.randint(255,size=(1,40,690,4))
        train_input_data_interweawed_normalized = []
        print "Storing train pic to numpy"
        part = 0
        for i in xrange(100000):
            print resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
            if resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss > 2298842112/10:
                print "Max ram storing part: " + str(part) + " At entry: " + str(i)
                print "Storing Train input"
                file_name = 'train_input_'+'part_'+str(part)+'_'+str(dim)+'_'+str(total_frames_with_deltas)+'_window_height_'+str(window_height)+'.h5'
                store_file(file_name,train_input_data_interweawed_normalized)
                part = part + 1             
                del train_input_data_interweawed_normalized
                gc.collect()
                train_input_data_interweawed_normalized = []
                raw_input("something")
            for plot in train_files:
                overlaps_reshaped = np.random.randint(10,size=(45,200,5,3))
                for ind_plot in overlaps_reshaped.reshape(overlaps_reshaped.shape[1],overlaps_reshaped.shape[0],overlaps_reshaped.shape[2],overlaps_reshaped.shape[3]): 
                    ind_plot_reshaped = ind_plot.reshape(ind_plot.shape[0],1,ind_plot.shape[1],ind_plot.shape[2])
                    train_input_data_interweawed_normalized.append(ind_plot_reshaped)
    print len(train_input_data_interweawed_normalized)

    return train_input_data_interweawed_normalized_print
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

saved = False
train_input = load_data_overlap(saved)
```

output:

```
.....
223662080
224772096
225882112
226996224
228106240
229216256
230326272
Max ram storing part: 0 At entry: 135
Storing Train input
something
377118720
Max ram storing part: 1 At entry: 136
Storing Train input
something
377118720
Max ram storing part: 2 At entry: 137
Storing Train input
something
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bit bulky for a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is concerned with freeing memory inside a `for` loop by saving a long list to file, then deleting the list. Try cutting everything inside the `for plot in train_files:` loop and just add a list of [random variables](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html) to your list for each point in the loop. Then provide some of the output.

Comment: added new version and output

Comment: you've removed the `del` statements. Also, rather than saving the whole array to a new variable (and taking up twice as much memory in the process), why not save it then just delete it:

`h5f.create_dataset('train_input', data=np.concatenate(train_input_data_interweawed_normalized,axis=1))`

Comment: You mean something like this? : https://pastebin.com/25MtFeii

Comment: yes, but without all this: `train_input_data_interweawed_normalized = None
                train_input_data_interweawed_normalized = []
                del h5f`. What is the updated output?

Comment: well.. I need `train_input_data_interweawed_normalized = []` as it is being used in the for loop..  but it still causes the same problem.

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. It looks like the memory is still being doubled, so it's probably got something to do with how `h5py` is storing the data in memory before writing. Depending on your platform, you may want to experiment with different [file drivers](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html) when initialising your `h5py.File`

Comment: sooo?.. 

`h5f = h5py.File('train_input_'+'part_'+str(part)+'_'+str(dim)+'_'+str(total_frames_with_deltas)+'_window_height_'+str(window_height)+'.h5',driver=H5FD_SEC2 ,'w')`

Comment: Well.. wait.. using `none` is what is recommended... so what else are you suggesting?

Comment: Using `none` is recommended, but may be causing you problems. It depends on your platform. You could also try using `with` to open the file, as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863342/close-an-open-h5py-data-file), which explicitly closes the file. Or handle each file with a function call, as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675838/python-hdf5-h5py-issues-opening-multiple-files?rq=1).

Comment: `def store_file(file_name,data):
 with h5py.File(file_name,'w') as f:
  f["train_input"] = np.concatenate(data,axis=1)`

still same problem..

Comment: It seem that the memory increase occur when i np.concatenate the data.. 
I don't think it is due to `h5py`.

Comment: which versions of hdf5 and h5py are you using?

Comment: `np.concatenate` do use the double memory...  so it makes sense that is the killer. but it is not being removed. Versions are...

Comment: `>>> h5py.__version__
'2.7.0'`

Comment: i don't use hdf5

Comment: "i don't use hdf5" - if you're using OSX, I think you do. To test if it's the concatenation, lower your memory threshold before writing to disk. Set it to something really low and see if it completes a write to disk correctly.

Comment: I am not able to put it to a low value due to the `range` taking a lot of space...

Comment: The memory is the same after one save.. the memory never decrement from its last value, meaning something isn't getting probably deleted.

Comment: Warning: homebrew/science/hdf5-1.8.16_1 already installed

Comment: This thread has already gone on far too long in the comments. moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/56955/releasing-memory-usage-by-variable-in-python?tab=general)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly force garbage collection, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python):

> According to Python Official Documentation, you can force the Garbage Collector to release unreferenced memory with `gc.collect()`

Comment: OK, did you do it inside the loop after each `del`? Can you provide (in the question text) the memory usage as the program runs? Or, if you're feeling generous. a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The example given above is a minimum complete working example - Randomly generated data - The actually process i am doing, and the storing.  You should be able to run the code as it is. 

I used the garbage collector just before raw_input("Something!") And then saw that memory usage increased from last value.. I will add the output of the code.

Comment: see comment on question