# Unable to open a previously opened H5

Tags: python, h5py

I have a simple python script that opens an H5 file, edits some of the data and closes it. For some reason it works the first time I run the script but in crashes on the second try.

I was expecting that the error was that I do not close the file but actually I do. As you can see below I edit the fields called backR frontR and I create two new ones Manufacturer and Status then I close.

```
f = h5py.File(filename, 'r+')
backR = f['back_R']
backR[...] = SelectedBackCoat
frontR = f['front_R']
frontR[...] = SelectedFrontCoat
f.create_dataset('manufacturer', data=SelectedManu)
f.create_dataset('status', data=SelectedState)
f.close()
```

The second time I run the script for the same file to treat I get the following:

```
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 85, in h5py.h5f.open

OSError: Unable to open file (file is already open for read-only)
```

Comment: Seems, like the file is still opened. Are sure f.close() was called? Maybe there was some Exception? If you use a `with` statement when opening, then the close() will be called automatically: `with h5py.File(filename, 'r+') as f:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is still opened, maybe your script didn't reach `f.close()`? From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56624292/1749882) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29863342/close-an-open-h5py-data-file), you can try to force close all opened files first. Although you should  really debug why your file is still opened.

> pytables (which h5py uses) keeps track of all open files and provides
>   an easy method to force-close all open hdf5 files.

```
import tables
tables.file._open_files.close_all()
```

If you use the `with` statement you can enforce closing of file, even if a exception occurs:

```
with h5py.File(filename, 'r+') as f:
    f.write(...)
```

Comment: I think indeed my script never reaches f.close() as it crashes when trying to open the h5 file. I tried adding both the tables command and with statement but still i get same error

Comment: @AnderArbideNieto is this file opened somewhere else? In an editor? Restart the os or close the file handles manually (depends if you are on linux or windows).

Comment: No, the file is not opened anywhere else. I tried the checking with Process Explorer if the file is opened somewhere else and also restarting os. Still get same message

Comment: Do you call h5py.File() multiple times? Because it allows you to open a single file multiple times, although this is clearly not a good idea. Also you wrote your script works when you call it the first time?

Comment: When in doubt about a file's behavior, I use other tools (besides Python code) to interrogate and verify the file. The simplest is HDFView from The HDF Group. Alternately you could use HDF Group utility h5dump or the PyTables utility ptdump.

Comment: @kcw78 Yeah, this seems like a good idea. But what made me think is that he wrote the script works the first time.

Comment: Also, I would verify behavior of PyTables `tables.file._open_files.close_all()` function and `h5py`. My quick tests indicate it does not close files opened with with `h5py`. Also, it is not in the PyTables documentation, so you have to view the source to understand behavior.

Comment: @Frieder, yes, it works the first time. He's opening with 'r+', tries to write some data, and doesn't close properly on exception. My thoughts: maybe the file is corrupted?

Comment: Update: Thanks for all the replies. I found out the problem, in some previous code line a class was called where the file was opened for some other purpose. I did not notice that the class was built in a way it opened the file by default. Thanks a lot for the help.